# Excel 365: How to extract data from one sheet and automatically sort it WITH DUPLICATES

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, duplicate, microsoft-excel-365

I have a small gaming table, of about 100 entries, with **constant data updates**.

*Sheet: Officers*

```
Name      | Def | HP  |
-----------------------
John      | 10  | 50  |
-----------------------
Doe       | 10  | 100 |
-----------------------
Jane      | 50  | 50  |
-----------------------
Doean     | 100 | 10  |
-----------------------
...+100 rows (or so)
-----------------------
```

**The name of the ranges are `Name` (Officers!A:A), `Defence` (Officers!B:B) & `Health` (Officers!C:C)**

In a separate sheet, I am trying to have them (automatically) sorted by their stats, **using a formula AND without altering the original data in the Officers sheet**. However, I am stuck with the duplicates.

At first, I started to use the function `LARGE()` to extrapolate my data automatically, in combination with `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`. **Then I noticed a peculiar "bug" when some data is duplicated.**

*Sheet: Stats*

```
| A |     B     |  C  |  D  |
-----------------------------
|     Sorted by Defence     |
|----------------------------
| # | Character | Def | HP  |
-----------------------------
| 1 | Doean     | 100 | 10  |
-----------------------------
| 2 | Jane      | 50  | 50  |
-----------------------------
| 3 | John      | 10  | 50  |
-----------------------------
| 4 | John      | 10  | 50  |
-----------------------------



| (E/space) |     F     |  G  |  H  |
-------------------------------------
|           |   Sorted by Health    |
-------------------------------------
|           | Character | Def | HP  |
-------------------------------------
|           | Doe       | 10  | 100 |
-------------------------------------
|           | John      | 10  | 50  |
-------------------------------------
|           | John      | 10  | 50  |
-------------------------------------
|           | Doean     | 100 | 10  |
-------------------------------------
```

This is the formula I am using (in the sheet `Stats`):

```
Stats!A3: `=INDEX(Officers!$A:$C,MATCH(LARGE(Defense, $A3),Defense,0 ), 1)`
Stats!B3: `=INDEX(Officers!$A:$C,MATCH(LARGE(Defense, $A3),Defense,0 ), 2)`
Stats!C3: `=INDEX(Officers!$A:$C,MATCH(LARGE(Defense, $A3),Defense,0 ), 3)`
```

As you can see, it sorts but I am struggling with the duplicates (like `John` & `Doe` with `10 Def` OR `John` & `Doean` with `10 HP`)

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio EXCEL 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `SORTBY` function. As an example if you sorted data will be in column E and Column I, you can use the formulae to sort per defense and health respectively:

```
=SORTBY(A2:C5,B2:B5,-1)
```

```
=SORTBY(A2:C5,C2:C5,-1)
```

[image]

The `SORTBY` function will dynamically pull the result.

Comment: So, I can use `SORTBY` to sort by `Def` AND then `HP` if there's a duplicate in `Def`?

Comment: @Omar Does the officers sheet has duplicates? or only the result of your formula?

Comment: No duplicates, just the stats have "duplicate" values at times. Is there a way to limit the number of row outputs? No duplicates.

Comment: @Omar for unique values in case of duplicates you might combine the formulae on the answer with the `UNIQUE` function i.e. `=UNIQUE(SORTBY(A2:C5,B2:B5,-1)). to limit the rows combine INDEX and SEQUENCE. Something like: `=INDEX(SORTBY(A2:C5,B2:B5,-1), SEQUENCE(3.2)` for the sequence to return 3 rows and 2 columns, but I have not tested it.

Comment: THANK you!!! <3